# How to add new column based on existing column in a datatable in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to build a code to process text file from a fingerprint machine into a report.

text file input example,

`001;0000000000200004;01-07-2016;15:31;01;01`

with semicolon delimiter,

`machinecode;personid;dateDD-MM-YYYY;timeHH:MM;jobid;unused`

this is my last successful code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Adventa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AbsensiALU\AbsensiALU\Absen.txt")
    Dim tblabsen = New DataTable
    Dim colCount = lines.First.Split(";"c).Length

    For i As Int32 = 1 To colCount
        'Dim header As String
        tblabsen.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_" & i, GetType(String)))
    Next
    For Each line In lines
        Dim objFields = From field In line.Split(";"c)

        Dim newRow = tblabsen.Rows.Add()


        newRow.ItemArray = objFields.ToArray()

    Next
    Dim table1 As New DataTable
    table1 = tblabsen.Copy()

    table1.Columns(0).ColumnName = "No. Mesin"
    table1.Columns(1).ColumnName = "NIK"
    table1.Columns(2).ColumnName = "Tanggal"
    table1.Columns(3).ColumnName = "Jam"
    table1.Columns(4).ColumnName = "Keterangan"

    DataGridView1.DataSource = table1
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumn(0)
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumn(1)
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumn(2)
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumn(3)
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumn(4)

    DataGridView1.Columns(5).Visible = False


    Dim rowData As String = ""

    'dt is the name of the data table
    For Each row As DataRow In table1.Rows
        For Each column As DataColumn In table1.Columns
            rowData = rowData & column.ColumnName & "=" & row(column) & " "
        Next
        rowData = rowData & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    Next



End Sub



Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick


End Sub

End Class
```

now i want to add a column into it that based on table1.columns(4) with probably an IF/CASE operator, so the new columns for example will be like this

```
Dim kete As String
Select Case tblabsen.Columns(4).GetType.ToString()
            Case "00"
                kete = "Masuk"
            Case "01"
                kete = "Pergi"
            Case "02"
                kete = "Kembali"
            Case "03"
                kete = "Pulang"
            Case Else
                kete = "Error"
        End Select
```

assuming that 'kete' could be written into the new column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have create your own `DataTable`, so you need to add one extra column first

```
For i As Int32 = 1 To colCount + 1
    'Dim header As String
    tblabsen.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_" & i, GetType(String)))
Next
```

After that, you need to assign your value in `ForEach`

```
For Each line In lines
    Dim objFields = line.Split(";"c).ToList()
    Dim newRow = tblabsen.Rows.Add()

    Dim kete As String
    Select Case objField(4).GetType.ToString()
        Case "00"
            kete = "Masuk"
        Case "01"
            kete = "Pergi"
        Case "02"
            kete = "Kembali"
        Case "03"
            kete = "Pulang"
        Case Else
            kete = "Error"
    End Select
    objFields.Add(kete)

    newRow.ItemArray = objFields.ToArray()
Next
```

And also you need to handle this extra column in the rest of your code (i.e. resize, column name)

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex, it does solve my problem for adding new column, but the new column or 'kete' value is always "error" or we can say that the SELECT operator is not working, and i have no idea about it. Maybe I'll also have to figure out how to extract a single cell or column for future reference.

Comment: @JoeAdventa Have you try to see what you have in debug mode? And I believe we can omit `.GetType.ToString()`

Comment: I just remove `.GetType.ToString()` and it worked. Now I'll have to learn about calculating value before adding new column variable. Thank you very much Alex.